# Address book data persistence?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

(storyboard image)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUZ12.png

Have 3 text fields where user inputs data and saves it. Upon opening the application, if there is any save data, the previous input is displayed within the text fields. Problem is, there is only one set of data, while it needs to be an array with multiple people's information. I would like to instead create a navigation controller with cells with names and upon clicking on them it displays the correlating contact info.

viewcontroller.h

```
   @interface ArchiveViewController : UIViewController
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *name;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *address;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *phone;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *dataFilePath;
    - (IBAction)saveData:(id)sender;
    @end
```

viewcontroller.m

```
@interface ArchiveViewController ()

@end

@implementation ArchiveViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
 NSFileManager *filemgr;
 NSString *docsDir;
 NSArray *dirPaths;

 filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

 // Get the documents directory
 dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
   NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

 docsDir = dirPaths[0];

 // Build the path to the data file
 _dataFilePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir
        stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"data.archive"]];

 // Check if the file already exists
 if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: _dataFilePath])
 {
         NSMutableArray *dataArray;

         dataArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver
          unarchiveObjectWithFile: _dataFilePath];

         _name.text = dataArray[0];
         _address.text = dataArray[1];
         _phone.text = dataArray[2];
 }

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)saveData:(id)sender {
     NSMutableArray *contactArray;

     contactArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     [contactArray addObject:self.name.text];
     [contactArray addObject:self.address.text];
     [contactArray addObject:self.phone.text];
     [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject: 
       contactArray toFile:_dataFilePath];

}
@end
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having an array with 3 elements of text in it and using `NSKeyedArchiver`, have an array with dictionaries in it and save it with `writeToFile:atomically:`. This will use the array as a list of 'entries' rather than a list of fields and will save the data in a plist instead of a binary file.

Now, when you read in the array you can display a table view of the entries (just showing the name for example) and then when you show the archive view you would pass the controller the a appropriate dictionary.

For saving, it would be good to use delegation to pass the edit back to the master controller. But it could also be done directly (requires more knowledge in the detail controller) or by notification.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you think that the approach im taking to create a addressbook-like app is a good approach?

Comment: You haven't given a lot of detail on the overall structure. It would be a table view in a navigation controller, which I would say is correct. On iPad you could maybe use a collection view to provide a more interesting interface...